# Frame on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, frame

I have this class:

```
extension UIViewController {  
    func waiting() -> UIView{  
        let strLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))  
        strLabel.text = "Aguarde..."  
        strLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()  
        let messageFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 90, y: view.frame.midY - 25 , width: 180, height: 50))  
        messageFrame.layer.cornerRadius = 15  
        messageFrame.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.40)  
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.White)  
        activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)  
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()  
        messageFrame.addSubview(activityIndicator)  
        messageFrame.addSubview(strLabel)  
        view.addSubview(messageFrame)  

        return messageFrame  
    }  
}
```

When I need use this class I use:

```
class MyController: UIViewController{  
  ....  

  func x(){  
     let messageFrame = waiting()  
     //my code  
     messageFrame.removeFromSuperview()  
  }  
}
```

The problem is when the frame is showed if I touch anywhere on my app this frame is hidden. I need that when this frame is showed other options staying disabled, when I finish the frame, the options of app is enabled again. How can I do it?

Comment: Help full - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975321/how-do-i-show-and-or-hide-a-subview-using-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the view that you are returning a bit:

1. Make a "container" view that has the same frame as the view controller's view.  Give this view a "clear" background.
2. Make a "background" view, same size as the "container" view and add it to the container.  Give this view a black background and an alpha of, say, 0.4.
3. Now put the view that you are currently building in your "waiting" method, and add it to the "container" view (NOT to the background view, this should be a sibling of the background view, otherwise your alert will also be transparent).
4. Make sure all user interaction is disabled on your views (might only need it disabled on the "container" view).

This gives you a container view that covers the entire screen, and it has 2 children: a transparent background of the same size, and your current "waiting" alert thing.

Now if you add the "container" view to your view controller's view, the user can only touch on the container view which does nothing.

(Keep in mind that this doesn't handle screen rotation...you will have to do that yourself if needed.)